# Clustered Apache 2.4 LoadBalancer displays no content on /balancer-manager

Tags: load-balancing, cluster, apache-2.4, corosync

I have a Clustered Loadbalancer (pacemaker, corosync, apache 2.4) on CentOS 7.
There are two configuration files, one for the actual balanced site and one for the balancer-manager. When I access the balancer-manager site, it practically displays an empty page (**Load Balancer Manager for 10.0.0.20**..... Server Version, Server Build ------------------ *END*), just like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233637/apache-load-balancer-manager-displays-nothing)  - but wherever I put the SetHandler directive (directly into the vhost1.conf, into the httpd.conf etc.) it just stays the same.
I also get an HTTP 200 in the logs on request.

vhost1.conf:

```
<Virtualhost x.x.x.x:443>
 SSLEngine On
.....
.....
 <Proxy balancer://mycluster>
  ProxySet failonstatus=503
  BalancerMember http://10.0.0.21 loadfactor=5 connectiontimeout=2 retry=600
  BalancerMember http://10.0.0.22 loadfactor=5 connectiontimeout=2 retry=600
  BalancerMember http://10.0.0.23 loadfactor=1 connectiontimeout=2 retry=600

  ProxySet lbmethod=bybusyness
 </Proxy>

 ProxyPass /myservices/ balancer://mycluster/myservices/
 ProxyPassReverse /myservices/ balancer://mycluster/myservices/
</VirtualHost>
```

vhost2.conf:

```
Listen 10.0.0.20:8008
<VirtualHost 10.0.0.20:8008>
 <Location /balancer-manager>
  SetHandler balancer-manager
  Require ip 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2
 </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Does anyone have an idea why there is nothing being displayed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have add balancer-manager handler in same virtualhost where you have configured load balancer. Also need you need to exclude location with **"ProxyPass /balancer-manager !"**.

Please see the below virtualhost

```
<Virtualhost x.x.x.x:443>
  SSLEngine On
  ServerName abc.xyz.com
  .....
<Location /balancer-manager>
  SetHandler balancer-manager
  Require ip 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2
 </Location>

ProxyPass /balancer-manager !

<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
  ProxySet failonstatus=503
  BalancerMember http://10.0.0.21 loadfactor=5 connectiontimeout=2 retry=600
  BalancerMember http://10.0.0.22 loadfactor=5 connectiontimeout=2 retry=600
  BalancerMember http://10.0.0.23 loadfactor=1 connectiontimeout=2 retry=600
  ProxySet lbmethod=bybusyness
 </Proxy>

 ProxyPass /myservices/ balancer://mycluster/myservices/
 ProxyPassReverse /myservices/ balancer://mycluster/myservices/
</VirtualHost>
```

With above Virtuahost config you can access balancer manager via **abc.xyz.com/balancer-manager**